# How can I make the user names of commentors clickable links to the user's profile from the admin comment screen?

Tags: admin, comments, users, profiles, user-meta

I've set up my wordpress blog to only allow logged in users to leave comments, but I need a way for the administrator to be able to go to a user's profile from the comment moderation screen. I don't have profile pages set up, just the regular edit profile pages. Any advice is much appreciated.

Thank you!